# Is it possible to create a virtual layer based upon virtual (geometry) fields of another layer ?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to put an x/y offset to the point-geometry-layer to get map-tip-informations from all overlapping points like in the Point Displacement Renderer.

For getting map-tip-informations it seems to be important that the point is visible at the stored coordinate and is not modified by an offset in the renderer. So I have to recalculate the stored coordinates and modify it with a varying offset which depends for example on the actual scale. With this recalulated, displaced coordinates I'm trying to create a new layer. This displaced points should be recognized by map-tips.

I created a virtual fields (X_modified, y_modified) and virtual_geometry with the field name "geometry" (by "geom_from_wkt('Point(X_modified || Y_modified)') - but there is no geometry-field-type available.
The virtual layer didn't recognize the virtual geometry or other virtual fields...

-> Is it possible to create a virtual layer based upon virtual (geometry) fields of another layer ?

The calculation of the modified coordinates in the postgresql-data-provider seems not to be possible, because i do not know how to transfer the actual scale-variables (or other ones) from qgis to postgresql and its view-definitons. Or - do you know a way to do this ?
[QGIS 2.18]

Answer (score 1):

Unable to comment, so I'll have a stab at answering (possible badly), but to clarify:
- You have a layer containing points
- You would like to be able to access a point's location when creating map-tips
- You do not want the point symbol to render over the actual x, y coordinates of the data, to improve visual clarity

I've always been an advocate of data/presentation separation so to me, storing the offsets seems like a bad idea anyway (the offset doesn't mean anything in the real world, it just helps you to visualise the data).

Why not use a data-defined override in the offset field of the style settings for that layer? You would be able to conditionally set the offset distance for different scales using the in-built variable available in the expression builder.

If you definitely want two layers: one for displaced and one for non-displaced points, then why not make sure there is a common id in both fields and perform a join? That way data for the original points should be available in the displaced points layer

Comment: I'd a approach like your suggested before, but as it seems still in qgis 2.18.3 the "map-tip"-function (and the "identify" function) does work for the displaced points (which are not at their stored/original position).